# Ruby Debugger with netbeans

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, netbeans, glassfish, jruby

I am newbie with Ruby.
I could not install debugger with Ruby 1.9 thats the only i downloaded netbeans 6.9. Now i am using Jruby but now i am getting the following error

please help!

```
Fast Debugger (ruby-debug-ide 0.4.6) listens on localhost:53114
C:/Program Files/NetBeans 6.9/ruby/jruby-     1.5.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require': load error: server --   java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'c': The specified module could not be found.
(LoadError)

    from C:/Program Files/NetBeans 6.9/ruby/jruby-1.5.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from C:/Program Files/NetBeans 6.9/ruby/jruby-1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/glassfish-1.0.3-universal-java/lib/glassfish.rb:2
    from C:/Program Files/NetBeans 6.9/ruby/jruby-1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/glassfish-1.0.3-universal-java/lib/glassfish.rb:31:in `require'
    from C:/Program Files/NetBeans 6.9/ruby/jruby-1.5.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from C:/Program Files/NetBeans 6.9/ruby/jruby-1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/glassfish-1.0.3-universal-java/bin/glassfish:54
    from C:/Program Files/NetBeans 6.9/ruby/jruby-1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/glassfish-1.0.3-universal-java/bin/glassfish:103:in `debug_program'
    from C:/Program Files/NetBeans 6.9/ruby/jruby-1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.6/bin/rdebug-ide:82
    from C:/Program Files/NetBeans 6.9/ruby/jruby-1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.6/bin/rdebug-ide:19:in `load'
    from C:\Program Files\NetBeans 6.9\ruby\jruby-1.5.0\bin\rdebug-ide:19
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the wiki for Ruby Debugging on Netbeans http://wiki.netbeans.org/RubyDebugging follow the steps and it should work fine. It work for me!